# Unable to call a method from another class [Java]

Tags: java, class, subclass

So I have three classes: Main, UserGroup, and User. In User I have three methods that are called in the UserGroup class and one which I am trying to call in the Main class. Using the methods in the User class I have created an ArrayList in UserGroup that has three different strings in each element (sorry if wrong term) and using the final method in the User class I am trying to change one of these strings.

The method I am trying to call is

```
public class User {
  String UserType;

  //some code removed

  public void setUserType(String x) {
      if ("user editor admin".contains(x)) {
          UserType = x;
      } 
      else {
        UserType = "editor";
      }
  }
}
```

I am trying to call this on a UserGroup called administrators that has an arraylist in it by putting this in main:

```
editors.setUserType("editor");
```

as this is how I called the other methods from UserGroup but I get an error of

```
error: cannot find symbol
        editors.setUserType("editor");
                      ^
symbol:   method setUserType(String)
location: variable editors of type UserGroup
1 error
```

EDIT (more of my main):

I create a UserGroup editors by

```
UserGroup editors = new UserGroup();
```

and add values to the ArrayList with

```
editors.addValues();
```

and then print the elements

```
editors.printData();
```

this all works as those methods are in the UserGroup class.

Comment: Still get the same error except the symbol is now "method setUserType(String)

Comment: editors is not a User object.

Comment: Can you show us more of your main?

Comment: Please consider pasting code of main and usergroup classes as well. Clearly you have a compilation error resulting from trying to call a method that does not exist.

Comment: What if `x = "edit"`? You should really individually check your x values.

Comment: A `UserGroup` **is not** a `User` (*location: variable editors of type UserGroup*). Post `UserGroup`.

Comment: `editors` is of type `UserGroup` but you need a `User` object, so, please post more code of these classes and please follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): `Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.`

Comment: How is the connection between UserGroup and User? Are they related with inheritance or something?

Comment: What's inside `UserGroup` class? Please consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help sooner. As it is, we cannot give much help but guessing what might be wrong. Read my above comment too, there are 2 useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to read into the topic [overloading of methods in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

It looks for the method with the header

```
public void setUserType()
```

but you only defined the method

```
public void setUserType(String x)
```

So you should call the method you created with something like:

**editors.setUserType("Foobar")**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like editors is not actual a User.  Maybe it is a List< User > in which case, it would be

```
editors.get(i).setUserType(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does UserGroup contain a collection of User objects?

setUserType(...) is defined on User, but doesn't seem to be defined on UserGroup.

There are a couple of ways to do what you're trying to do.

1. Grab the list of User objects from your UserGroup, and call setUserType(...) on each one individually in main.  Something like:

   ```
   List<User> users = editors.getUsers() //assuming UserGroup.getUsers() exists
   for(User user : users)
       user.setUserType("whatever");
   ```
2. Add a method to UserGroup called setUserType(...) that iterates through its collection of User objects and sets the types:

   ```
   public setUserType(String type) {
   for(User user : users) //assuming you have a collection of User objects
       user.setUserType(type);
   ```

   }

If I'm describing this incorrectly, please add the complete implementation of UserGroup (or at least the part that shows how Users are contained), and we can provide more info.